# Why does setting padding on an element affect all siblings in the same div

Tags: html, css

In this fiddle I have a load of divs, an input and some images that are displayed inline. I want to shift the images down a bit so it looks nicely aligned, but when I apply padding or margin, it simply pushes down every element inside the container.

```
<div class="rs-paging">
    <div class="rs-pageclick">
        <img class="rs-selectfirst" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2296/fidelity/32/arrow_left.png" alt="" title="First Page">
    </div>



.rs-pageclick img {
    cursor:pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/qds8pnfx/2/

I've tried display:table/table-cell, no difference. I started without the images in container divs and that was just the same. vertical-align:top doesn't seem to help. And it ssems the same with padding or margin.

I don't really want to resort to position absolute/relative as I think there should be a way with simply setting padding. This is driving me nuts !

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `overflow:hidden` and fixing height for divs seem to work and fit your requests (I added a div containing all the text ones) :

https://jsfiddle.net/qds8pnfx/5/

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the best of the two answers, although Rijkvans explanation was also very good.

Answer (score 4):

The elements are all set to `display: inline-block;`. When you give one of the elements a `margin-top`, you push the whole line down.

Are you trying to get the items to align vertically? If so, you could use `vertical-align: middle;` on the `inline-block` elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/nea4w6h3/1/

Comment: thanks, thats helping, but I was hoping for some fine control on exactly how each element is aligned. So for example how could I shift down the "input" by 3px without affecting the rest of it ?

Comment: You could add position: relative; to the specific element, and modify its position relative to its original position with the top, right, bottom and left properties.

Comment: After remove the height property of my element, the ```vertical-align``` works really good.  Thanks !